# dynamically set value to sonar properties file

Tags: sonarqube

I have a sonar properties file in which i want to assign the value dynamically to sonar.branch.target only if the branch is not master. I have a build parameter ${env.BRANCH_NAME} to assign value.

```
sonar.login=
sonar.password=
sonar.host.url=
sonar.projectKey=xxxx
sonar.projectName="yyyyy"
sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0
sonar.sources=src/app
sonar.test=src/app
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.ts.tslintconfigpath=tslint.json
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
sonar.typescript.exclusions=**/node_modules/**,**/typings.d.ts,**/main.ts,**/environments/environment*.ts,**/*routing.module.ts
if [ ${env.BRANCH_NAME} != "master" ]; then
    sonar.branch.target= "master"
    sonar.branch.name= ${env.BRANCH_NAME}
    echo "inside if statement"
fi
```

I want to execute this logic while my build param is not equal to master. But the if block is executing irrespective of this logic. Please help correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution for the same. sonar-project.properties file has been changed as below to make it work.

```
if [ ${env.BRANCH_NAME} != "master" ]
then
  SONAR_BRANCH=${env.BRANCH_NAME}
  SONAR_TARGET=master
else
  SONAR_BRANCH=${env.BRANCH_NAME}
  SONAR_TARGET=
fi
sonar.login=
sonar.password=
sonar.host.url=
sonar.projectKey=
sonar.projectName=
sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0
sonar.sources=src/app
sonar.test=src/app
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.ts.tslintconfigpath=tslint.json
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
sonar.typescript.exclusions=**/node_modules/**,**/typings.d.ts,**/main.ts,**/environments/environment*.ts,**/*routing.module.ts
sonar.branch.name=${SONAR_BRANCH}
sonar.branch.target= ${SONAR_TARGET}
```

Comment: can u please explain how does it work? I mean sonar.branch.name will know that gitlab/github has changes on expected branch?

Comment: Sorry Den. I am not following. Can you let me know your problem statement?